# Are $L^p$ norms absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $1 < K \leq \infty$, and suppose $f \in L^p (X)$ for all $1 \leq p \leq K$, for $X$ some $\sigma$-finite measure space with no atoms.

**Question:** Is the function $p \to \|f\|_{L^p}$ absolutely continuous on $[1, K]$? (on $[1, \infty)$ instead for $K = \infty$)

Comment: You can just use Fubini to integrate the formal derivative $\int |f|^p\log |f|$ (this is continuous in $p$ by dominated convergence) to confirm that $p\mapsto \|f\|^p_p$ and thus also the norm itself is AC. This shows that the norm is AC on $[0,K)$. At the endpoint, matters are not immediately clear since the integral above can diverge.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I believe this argument shows that $f$ is locally AC, i.e. AC on $[0, R]$ for all $R < K$, however the argument doesn't necessarily show f is AC on $[0, K)$ (or equivalently, $[0, K]$).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\newcommand\norm[1]{\lVert#1\rVert}\newcommand\abs[1]{\lvert#1\rvert}$Sure, the $L^p$-norm is absolutely continuous (and more). Let me first prove it in the case when the total measure of $X$ is $1$, and then I will indicate what needs to be changed for the general case.

The key reason why I said we will start with the case of measure $1$ is that by the Hölder's inequality, $h(p) = \norm f_{L^p}$ is an increasing function (apply it to the functions $f$ and $1$). Next, this function is also continuous: for example, approximate your function by the simple functions in $L^K$-norm, for which the continuity is obvious, and then use that the uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous. Lastly, we need that for $p < K$ the function $h$ is actually smooth (this was already observed in the comments) — you can simply differentiate under the integral sign and bound $\abs f^p \log(\abs f)^m$ by $\abs f^K + 1$, say. So, we have an increasing continuous function on $[1, K]$, which is smooth on $[1, K)$. From this it follows that it is absolutely continuous (here it is crucial that $h$ is increasing, so that $\norm{h'}_{L^1} = h(K)-h(1) < \infty$).

For the general case, we just need to replace the property that $h$ is increasing with some surrogate which is good enough. This is again done with the help of the Hölder's inequality, just that we need a tiny bit more work. We already know smoothness on $(1, K)$, so we have to deal with the vicinities of $1$ and $K$. I will deal with the later, the former is done similarly. We have for $1 < q < p$
$$\norm f_{L^q} \le \norm f_{L^1}^{1-\theta} \norm f_{L^p}^{\theta},$$
where $\theta = \frac{1-1/q}{1-1/p}$. Note that $1-\theta \le c(p-q)$ for some absolute constant $c$, if both $p$ and $q$ are close enough to $K$. So, we can bound
$$\norm f_{L^q} \le C^{c(p-q)} \norm f_{L^p}^{\theta}\le C^{c(p-q)} \norm f_{L^p} \norm f_{L^p}^{\theta-1}.$$

Here we, on the other hand, need a lower bound for $\norm f_{L^p}$. There are probably more elegant ways to do it, but just notice that, unless $f\equiv 0$ (when there's nothing to prove), for some $\delta > 0$ we have $\abs{\{ x\in X\mid \abs{f(x)} > \delta\}} > \delta$, which gives us a constant lower bound for $\norm f_{L^p}$. So, in total we get
$$\norm f_{L^q} \le C'^{(p-q)} \norm f_{L^p}.$$

So, the function $\norm f_{L^q}C'^{q}$ is increasing. It is also again continuous and smooth on $(1, K)$. So, it is absolutely continuous. From this it follows that $\norm f_{L^q}$ is absolutely continuous as well.

Comment: This looks great, I'll read it and get back to you soon.

Comment: I will accept this post since it came first, but thank you also @Lorenzo Pompilli for your answer.

Comment: This answer is better, mine was incomplete x) I added a comment to address the remaining part

Answer (score 6):

A simply written proof is the following. The interpolation inequality
$$\|f\|_{L^{p_\theta}}\leq\|f\|_{L^{p_0}}^{1-\theta}\|f\|_{L^{p_1}}^\theta, $$
$$ \frac{1}{p_\theta}=\frac{1-\theta}{p_0}+\frac{\theta}{p_1} $$
implies immediately that the function $\sigma\mapsto \log(\|f\|_{L^{1/\sigma}})$ is convex.

Convex functions on an interval are continuous. Moreover, by the convexity of the above function, the interval $[1,K]$ can be split in (at most) two subintervals on which the function $p\mapsto \log(\|f\|_{L^p})$ is continuous and monotone. Thus also $p\mapsto \|f\|_{L^p}$ is monotone on two disjoint intervals, hence it is AC.

Comment: Huh, yes, this is a much faster way to get monotonicity!

Comment: But monotonicity alone is not sufficient. You need smoothess in the interior, as in the other answer.

Comment: Of course, sorry. For some reason my brain skipped that part

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune But it's also true that convex functions are locally AC, and composition of smooth and AC functions is locally AC (and invertible smooth change of variables like $\sigma\mapsto p=\sigma^{-1}$ preserve local AC-ity), so one can obtain the absolute continuity simply from the interpolation property. This way one does not need to differentiate the function $p\mapsto \|f\|_{L^p}$ X)

Comment: Yes, you don't need smoothness to get absolute continuity, it's automatic from the convexity. However, what you do need is continuity up to endpoints -- it is true that the convex functions are continuous on $(1, K)$ but you need to say some words about how we get continuity at $1$ and $K$.

Comment: Good point. For the continuity up to the endpoints, the interpolation property is not enough